# display multiply calculations from input data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I'm busy with one project with REACT and faced a problem. I have user input data. I use it in some math formulas and need to display all results in one table. The problem is, that result2 relies on the result1, result3 relies on the result2 etc.

```
 input data:
 const [volume, setVolume] = useState(0);
 const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
 const [fixedCosts, setFixedCosts] = useState(0);
```

results:

```
 const [revenue, setRevenue] = useState(volume * price);
 const [netProfit, setNetProfit] = useState(revenue - fixedCosts);
```

functions:

```
function handleFormSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  function handleRevenueChange() {
   setRevenue(volume * price);     // both values are from input
  }
  function handleNetProfitChange() {
   setNetProfit(Math.round(revenue - fixedCosts));  // revenue here is result of the first calculations
  }
 }
```

I retrieve data, I can use it and display. This part works. My problem: with the first submit, I calculate "revenue" in the first formula, so I change its state, but in the mean time its current state is 0. So the second formula gives nothing. When I press submit the second time, bcz "revenue" is already updated, I can use it and it calculates the second formula. So If I have there five functions, I need to press five times on submit, bcz every value state updates one by one (they rely on each other).

1. How can I calculate everything at first and then only display all data with one button submit.
2. Even better- how can I make data to be calculated and displayed automatically if there is any input without pressing button at all? (thinking about onBlur, but don't know how to use it, and stil issue to calculate everything first)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Check my answer. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need these lines at all:

```
const [revenue, setRevenue] = useState(volume * price);
const [netProfit, setNetProfit] = useState(revenue - fixedCosts);
```

Because `revenue` and `netProfit` depend on values from your component state,
when those input values are updated, the component will re-render with the latest state,
and your local variables `revenue` and `netProfit` will be updated as well:

For example:

```
export default function App() {
  const [volume, setVolume] = useState(0);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
  const [fixedCosts, setFixedCosts] = useState(0);

  // these two variables will update when the state changes
  const revenue = volume * price;
  const netProfit = revenue - fixedCosts;
  
  return (/* render something */);
}
```

See working toy example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-ritchie-8s0jc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve your goal by returning a **promise**, and then use this function with the `await`.

Here is the solution, try:

```
function handleFormSubmit(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  function handleRevenueChange() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
            setRevenue(volume * price);
            resolve(revenue);
        });
  }

  async function handleNetProfitChange() {
      const resultAsRevenue = await handleRevenueChange;
      setNetProfit(Math.round(resultAsRevenue - fixedCosts));
  }

}
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: there is nothing asynchronous about calculating two values. It doesn't need promises

Comment: useState hook set state async way. So, there is a need of promise.

Answer (score -1):

I think useEffect react hook can be used here

```
 function handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setRevenue(volume * price); 
 }

useEffect(()=>{
setNetProfit(Math.round(revenue - fixedCosts));
},[revenue])
```

Comment: useEffect is used for side effects. Calculating a value is not a side effect. With this solution, there will be at least 1 render with updated revenue and old net profit right after updating revenue and before callback for useEffect was called. Net profit (and other derived values) should update at the same time revenue was updated